# Styling a background in CSS3 with opacity?

Tags: css, styles

I have a simple css styling question. I've been trying to create this effect on a background to match a design but i just can't seem to get it right.

Here is what I have [image: my implemntation]

And here is the design

[image: the design]

does anyone have any tips to help me create that background effect? any help would be appreciated.

My code right now, if it helps:

```
.backgroundOverlay {
  background-image: url('../images/background-pattern.png'), linear-
  gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0,118,255,0.8), rgba(0,197,255,0.8));
  /* opacity: 0.3;  */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* padding: 15vw 5vw; */
```

}

The background image is just a repeated .png file

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.container .content{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.container::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:99;
  background-image: url("path/to/yourfile.png");
  background-size: repeat;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
     <img src="path/to/your/upper_frame.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```